# Expand cards the entire width

Tags: css, ionic-framework

[image]

Would anyone know the .css property to expand the cards the entire length of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding in the ion-content.
This makes the card to occupy the whole screen width.

```
<ion-content no-padding>
  <ion-card>
    ...
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```